# Not able to install DeviceAgent- No valid iOSDeveloperIdentities found on system

Tags: ios, ruby, nsrunloop, calabash-ios

**xcrun xcodebuild -version**: 9.2

**run_loop**: 2.6.4

**calabash-ios version**: 0.20.5

**iOS version**: 11.2.6

**Command**- `/Users/testmaskin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/run_loop-2.6.4/lib/run_loop/device_agent/bin/iOSDeviceManager install /Users/testmaskin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/run_loop-2.6.4/lib/run_loop/device_agent/ipa/DeviceAgent-Runner.app --device-id 61b08575d55927c0dd0b9192e37a2c1f421cd000`

**Output:**

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CBXException', 
reason: 'Unable to find appropriate codesign identity for device 61b08575d55927c0dd0b9192e37a2c1f421cd000 / app com.apple.test.DeviceAgent-Runner combo'
```

**Output of** `tail -F ~/.calabash/iOSDeviceManager/logs/current.log`

```
2018-03-20 16:46:04.676 INFO ShellRunner:70 | EXEC: /usr/bin/xcrun codesign -d --entitlements :- /Users/testmaskin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/run_loop-2.6.4/lib/run_loop/device_agent/ipa/DeviceAgent-Runner.app
2018-03-20 16:46:05.171 INFO ShellRunner:70 | EXEC: /usr/bin/xcrun codesign -d --entitlements :- /Users/testmaskin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/run_loop-2.6.4/lib/run_loop/device_agent/ipa/DeviceAgent-Runner.app
2018-03-20 16:46:05.258 INFO ShellRunner:70 | EXEC: /usr/bin/xcrun security find-identity -v -p codesigning
2018-03-20 16:46:05.466 ERROR ConsoleWriter:32 | No valid iOSDeveloperIdentities found on system.
```

However, the profile exists in the `/Users/testmaskin/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles` directory as well as the device UDID exists in that profile. See the output below.

```
$ /usr/bin/xcrun security find-identity -v -p codesigning
1) 95CC7E649668236B68C7D309A07AAC5E3C9B409B "iPhone Distribution: Polly Lal (***********)"
     1 valid identities found
```

Not sure what I'm missing here. I have a bunch of such test devices attached to their own Mac Mini hosts. Each of those setup are exhibiting this problem. So I'm sure its not because of a faulty device. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a distribution certificate. Someone pointed out that's not the right one. I generated a new developer certificate, regenerated the provisioning profile for that certificate and it worked!